# Asp.net randomly stops obeying forms authentication whitelist

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, forms-authentication

### The problem

Last month we move our asp.net website farm from Server 2008 R2 to Server 2012 R2 and upgraded to asp.net 4.5. We are using cookied forms authentication to prevent unauthorized access to the website.

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

We have certain assets and pages (ex: sign in page) that are whitelisted in the web.config:

```
<location path="signin">
   <system.web>
     <authorization>
       <allow users="*" />
     </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

Over the last few months we've been noticing that IIS/Asp.net randomly stops obeying the whitelist and assume everything needs to be authenticated. All requests to the site on that server will be redirected to the signin page which then throws a 500 error. No whitelisted assets can be retrieved.

There are then 2 errors in the event viewer that we can see when IIS is messed up. The first:

```
Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.PipelineModuleStepContainer.GetNextEvent(RequestNotification notification, Boolean isPostEvent, Int32 eventIndex)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
```

This second one doesn't show up all the time:

```
Event code: 4005 
Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied has expired.
```

The iis process will be working find for hours then all the sudden start doing this weirdness. As soon as we recycle the app pool, or even just modify the web.config the site starts working again.

### Things we've tried

Honestly we are quite stumped. This wasn't happening on our old servers, but we've made quite a few changes to our site since then but nothing related to authentication.

1. We are in a webfarm and we define our machine key inside of our web.config.

   ```
   <machineKey validationKey="XXX" decryptionKey="XXX" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
   ```
2. We are targeting asp.net 4.5

   ```
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="120" maxQueryStringLength="4096"  minFreeThreads="72" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="88"  maxRequestLength="32768" />
   ```
3. We recreated the application pool within IIS.
4. Not sure if it matters but we use IIS Shared Config and shared certificates.
5. The issue is happening on all of the web servers in the farm, not just one.
6. We reinstalled the OS on one of the servers yesterday... so we'll see if that fixes anything.
7. It doesn't seem to be tied to memory usage. Sometimes iis is only using 4gb, sometimes 6gb.
8. It doesn't seem to be tied to a certain page execution that we can tell.
9. I've run debug diag against a memory dump and there aren't any threads that are running long nor crazy memory usage.

Yea, we are stumped. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I could say mainly 2 reasons and causes for these kind of errors.

*** 500 internal server error mainly occurs if any errors exists in the web.config file (configuration file) like irregular XML syntax errors in connection strings,tags,providers,Frame work Version,file paths...etc.

***  If your website is being designed by Membership,Roles Concepts & Providers are not available while upgrading to new MySQL/SOL servers AUTHENTICATION FAILS. Since Providers are not available. Hence you may get 2nd error as Authentication Failed.

Comment: Looking at your *authorization* rules, first entry *denies all users who are anonymous(not authenticated)* and second entry *allows all users(everyone anonymous, authenticated)*. As per the precedence of rule, second entry *allows all users* to the site. Are you able to access *singin* page, where is the *authentication* configuration, can you please post it along with authorization rules for your whitelist assets.

Comment: @PalakBhansali - The rules are working correctly 99% of the time. Then they just stop working all together. So when it breaks I can't get to the sign in page, or any allowed asset (like images, css). It's super weird...

Comment: Have you checked this article, especially Troubleshooting Scenario 5:
http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/security-issues/troubleshooting-forms-authentication

Comment: are you sure that the session cookie can actually be written to the client?  I had a recent issue with newer versions of IE that older asp.net webforms did not recognise the user agent so assumed that it was a 'downlevel' browser.  adding `<forms cookieless="UseCookies" ... >` helped

Comment: I found the load balancing process incorrectly push existing users from one server to another, getting session credentials messed up. In my case I had to deal with a third party load balancer which we eventually switched off to resolve the problem.

Comment: @PaulLemke Just checking in here – did you guys ever resolve this issue? I'm seeing a somewhat similar issue on my web farm at the moment - very intermittent; we get the NullReferenceException and Ticket Supplied Has Expired entries in Event Viewer; nothing but an Application Pool recycle seems to fix it.

Comment: Just added an answer with what we ended up doing to fix it.... not the "root" cause for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question with what we did to solve the issue, even though we never did find the root cause. We noticed that the server would start ignoring the whitelist rules when it got too heavy under load. Not much load, maybe 40% utilization over the course of 5 minutes. After that it would start ignoring things.

The simple solution for us was to throw more hardware at the issue. We are running 6 webservers instead of 3. We haven't seen the whitelist issue since then. So honestly... we have no idea what's up.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience, changing IIS to allow anonymous authentication solved it for me. In your case, I would recommend 2 things:

1. Try Enabling Anonymous Authentication in IIS (Visit http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770966%28v=ws.10%29.aspx to see how)
2. Modifiy your code as shown below

```xml
<location path="signin">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, Stackoverflow stripped the xml, I had to format it manually.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't say exactly what the issue is, I can share a similar experience.
We had a site that used forms authentication and also assumed it was failing and forcing everyone to authenticate. What we discovered was that the website was crashing and IIS was returning the default website instead. It took us a while to figure out. You might want to check to make sure you're not looking at a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your Authentication node from your web.config ?
It should be something like this :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="Logon" loginUrl="~/Logon.aspx" protection="All" timeout="60" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

Are you using the asp.net session state server ? If you do check if the service asp.net state server is started.